# method with many parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a method with 20 parameters,( NSString, float,....), can i construct a type ( for example Enumerated, typdef) to invoque my method and not pass all my parameters ?

replace:
-(void)myMethodeParam1:...:param2:.... ;

with:
-(void)myMethode:MyNewTypeParam ;

tanks for your answers

Comment: How common are all of those elements in your code? Are they passed around together often?  If several of them are always grouped together (e.g. a name, an id, etc.) than a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) would be better suited for your needs, passing in the object instead of all of the params.

Comment: they are not grouped, my method is to construct an xml soap message to invoke a web services, and tyer require 20 parameters

Comment: Method with more that 5 parameters => engineering error, IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSDictionary (NSMutableDictionary). You'll need to wrap primitive type (like float) to obj-c objects (e.g. NSNumber) for that though.

E.g. you have 10 NSString params named param0,...,param9 then you can place them in NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *paramDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:string0, @"param0", string1, @"param1", ..., string9, @"param9", nil];
[obj myMethod: paramDict];
```

or if you can enumerate your variables somehow you can use NSMutableDictionary and add them to it in a loop.

Then in your method you can get your parameters from dictionary you have:

```
-(void)myMethode: (NSDictionary*)dict{
    NSString *string0 = [dict objectForKey:@"param0];
    //Do something with it
    ...
}
```

If your parameters together are some logical entity and they're usually used together you also can also create a custom class that contains them as instance variables